# Error compliling xml file

Tags: android

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content">


        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CLICK ME"
        android:id="@+id/textView">
        <requestFocus />
    </TextView>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

can someone please solve the error i am getting also i am facing error for low disc storage in android directory.please am stuck here and not getting any answers after browsing for hours.

```
  Error:(24) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
  C:\Users\abhilasha.abhilasha-
  PC.000\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\layout-
 v17\activity_main.xml
 Error:(2) Error parsing XML: no element found
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
 > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
 org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 
 'C:\Users\abhilasha.abhilasha-PC.000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\build-
 tools\26.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
 Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Have even you tried validating your XML?

Comment: Close your tags with a slash "/" when they do not have separated closing tags. Or even better, use design view to insert elements, and then look at "text " view to see how you should format.

Comment: Yes i did tried validating but it did not work.Even i tried closing tags with slash earlier so i tried separate tags closings.What else should i try on?

Comment: Remove all the leading whitespace in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

`No element found` for `<requestFocus />` so remove this tag if its not necessary.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">   

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CLICK ME"
        android:id="@+id/textView">

    </TextView>
  </RelativeLayout>
```